# copying file to /system with adb shell on Bluestacks 10

Tags: android, adb, bluestacks

I've been trying to copy a file to /system (to install a certificate) and when I try this as superuser, it tells me that /system... is a read-only file system. I've mounted the file system using "mount -o rw,remount,rw /system" but when I run "mount" it says that /system is still ro. I'm running Nougat32 on Bluestacks 10, and it's properly rooted.

Any ideas how I might be able to copy the file to /system?

I've also tried "hd-adb root" but when I run this, it simply gets stuck and I have to abort it with ctrl-c.

Comment: Emulators like BlueStacks don't have flash memory like physical devices where the partitions are saved, therefore they use a file in the host file-system that serves as virtual flash. If that file is read-only you can do want inside the emulator, writing will still fail. The same is true if the emulator opens this file read-only.